# Get normal of a Point3D

Tags: c#, math, geometry, vector-graphics

I have set of points. I created strip triangles using these points.

[image]

I am using HelixToolkit to draw these rectangles. Function requires list of pointes (triangles will be made using triangle strip) and set of normal vectors. Now I need to calculate normal. What I thought that for each triangle there should be a normal. But function says that for every point there will be a normal. I used three points to calculate normal of a triangle, but **how can I calculate normal of a point.**

So if am using the example shown in the figure what will be normal of All points (A, B, C, D, E, F).

Here is the method which I am calling.

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds a triangle strip to the mesh.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stripPositions">
/// The points of the triangle strip.
/// </param>
/// <param name="stripNormals">
/// The normal vectors of the triangle strip.
/// </param>
/// <param name="stripTextureCoordinates">
/// The texture coordinates of the triangle strip.
/// </param>
/// <remarks>
/// See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip.
/// </remarks>
public void AddTriangleStrip(
    IList<Point3D> stripPositions,
    IList<Vector3D> stripNormals = null,
    IList<Point> stripTextureCoordinates = null)
```

Here is what I have.

```
var points = new List<Point3D>();
// populate points.
// TODO: populate Normal for each point.
AddTriangleStrip(points, normal);
```

I used this method to calculate normal of a surface.

```
private static Vector3D CalculateNormal(Point3D firstPoint, Point3D secondPoint, Point3D thirdPoint)
{
    var u = new Point3D(firstPoint.X - secondPoint.X,
        firstPoint.Y - secondPoint.Y,
        firstPoint.Z - secondPoint.Z);

    var v = new Point3D(secondPoint.X - thirdPoint.X,
        secondPoint.Y - thirdPoint.Y,
        secondPoint.Z - thirdPoint.Z);

    return new Vector3D(u.Y * v.Z - u.Z * v.Y, u.Z * v.X - u.X * v.Z, u.X * v.Y - u.Y * v.X);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept like a *normal of Point*. Normal refers to a *surface* and not to a point, so I *presume* that we are talking here about *average normal of all neighbour faces of a given point* .

For this, you should know somehow from given point all connected to it faces. 
For every face calculate its normal and make an average of them

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was also assuming the same. So if there are 6 points that means 4 triangles (surfaces) and 4 normal. But method is confusing me. There is a check in method which throws exception if number of points and normal are different.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez: not necesssary onl 4 faces.There could be intersecting and overlapped faces too. The check refers to fact that for every point you should have its *average* normal, imo. SOif you have 6 points, you calculate 6 *average* normals

Comment: How to calculate 6 average normals?

Comment: @FaisalHafeez: I wrote that in my comment. Calculate for every connected to given point face its normal: face normal, after average should look like: Vectr3D avg = faceNormal1 + faceNormal2 + ...

Comment: in computer graphics, often the normal is assigned to the points instead of the surface. the "normals" of the surface can then be smoothly interpolated across the surface. this makes spheres with low polygon counts still appear high res